# Navbar isn't being rendered when switching routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to create a landing page for a specific route that I have created.  I want it to render a navigation bar with links to different pages at the top.  I'm able to get to my landing page `/tech-portal` and the navigation bar is rendered with all the correct links, but when I select `Page1`, it navigates to the link `/tech-portal/page1` with nothing rendered.  When I select the link I want the navbar to stay on the page and only change the content that is being rendered below it. How can I accomplish this with what I already have?

Index.js

```
ReactDOM.render((
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={App}/>
            <Route path='/service' component={ServiceReport} />

            <Route exact path='/inventory' component={InventorySystem} />
            <Route path='/inventory/tracking' component={PartTracker} />
            <Route path='/inventory/build-assembly' component={BuildAssembly} />
            <Route path='/inventory/import-purchase-order' component={ImportPO} />
            <Route path='/inventory/update-item' component={UpdateItem} />
            <Route path='/inventory/create-item' component={CreateItem} />
            <Route path='/inventory/receive-items' component={ReceiveItem} />

            <Route exact path='/tech-portal'>
                <TechPortalHome>
                    <Route path='/tech-portal/page1' component={Page1} />
                    <Route path='/tech-portal/page2' component={Page2} />
                </TechPortalHome>
            </Route>


        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>), document.getElementById('appRoot'));
```

TechPortalHome.js

```
import React from 'react'
import '../../StyleSheets/TechPortal.css';
import NavBar from '../../components/NavBar';


export default class TechPortalHome extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <NavBar></NavBar>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

NavBar.js

```
import React from 'react'
import '../StyleSheets/TechPortal.css';
import Logo from '../../public/Images/Logo.png';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';


export default class NavBar extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="headerdiv">
                    <div className='ImageDiv'>
                        <a href="../tech-portal">
                            <img className='LogoImage' name='Logo' src={Logo} alt="" />
                        </a>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="navbar">
                    <a>Home</a>
                    <Link to="/tech-portal/page1">Page1</Link>
                    <Link to="/tech-portal/page2">Page2</Link>
                    <a>Login</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I've looked online for something similar, but a lot of the stuff is outdated, or don't do a good job at explaining it.  If anyone give me some advice on how I could make this work that would be awesome.  Thanks!

**EDIT**

Changing `exact path` to just `path` in my `/tech-portal` route seems to work correctly.  The routes are changed and the content is displayed below the navbar.  Curious to see what other people think about the approach before closing this discusison.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that you are suppose to nest routes like that. You can make `/tech-portal/page1` and `/tech-portal/page2` routes to render the `TechPortalHome` using the render method. That way you can pass either `Page1` or `Page2` as childs to `TechPortalHome`.

Or you can create a route like `/tech-portal/{content}` to `TechPortalHome`, retrieve the `content` param there, and render the appropriate component then.

Comment: check my edit above.  This seemed to do the trick.  I'm not sure I understand your concern about doing it this way.  Could you explain why this wouldn't be a good idea.  This is the only way that I've been able to get nested routes to work.

Comment: Never saw or used nested routes and thought that caused problems. I checked the docs now and I saw it can be done, so I guess if it works now, there is no problem regarding nested routes

Comment: I guess i'm fairly new to nested routing so I don't know of the issues that can occur within them.  If you have some resources that show the concern, I would like to check them out.